# trustpilot widget sveltekit does not load after changing the page SPA

Tags: javascript, node.js, sveltekit

The widget is rendered only on 1st page load, after clicking on any link and going to another page, it disappears, however onMount triggers on every page load and after any click

the code:

let scriptLoaded = false;

```
onMount(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js';
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = () => {
    scriptLoaded = true; // Set flag when the script is loaded
  };
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

{#if scriptLoaded}


Trustpilot


{/if}

I tried afterUpdate, beforeUpdate, with and without scriptLoaded trigger, the result is always the same:
[after the 1st page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CiSw.png)
[after any link click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POI2g.png)

Comment: Finally got solved the issue. For any SPA you might ass this code inside onMount in order to trigger widget render:


`const trustbox = document.getElementById('trustbox');
window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(trustbox);`